# dotnet core fork child process in Linux

Tags: c#, linux

Now .net core works on cross platforms. But how does it calls fork() in Linux to create a child process ?

Like in python,using os libiray. os.fork() or os.exec()

Comment: You can't do that in Java, and I imagine you can't do it in .NET either. Instead, use threads for concurrency or the core libraries for running external programs.

Comment: If you are doing `fork`/`exec` you can use `System.Diagnostics.Process` instead.

Comment: You could also P/Invoke `fork` or `daemonize` but that would be a very bad idea.

Comment: @NetMage - Could you please provide more information (or a link) about why P/Invoking `fork` is a bad idea?